# Trabajar con el texto seleccionado por el usuario

Tags: javascript, html

Buenas,

Sigo con un tema que está haciendo romperme la cabeza, pero no doy con la tecla. En un editor de texto como en el que estoy escribiendo ahora, tengo unos iconos, que al tocarlos, se añaden unas etiquetas en el textarea. Pero tengo una serie de problemas:

- Las etiquetas se ponen en orden según las voy pulsando, esto a priori bien, pero no es práctico ni funcional, puesto que lo normal muchas veces es escribir una parrafada y después seleccionar el texto que quieres poner en negrita.
- Aunque seleccione un trozo de texto, las etiquetas aparecen en los extremos de TODO el texto.

He buscado información y en principio se puede trabajar con `window.getSelection()`, he probado algún script, pero no me acaba de dar ningún resultado.

Tal y como tengo el código ahora, al pulsar sobre un botón, el de poner el texto en negrita por ejemplo, se ejecuta un script, el cual recibe 3 parámetros, uno de ellos es el texto, pero no el texto seleccionado, sino el texto de todo el textarea, creo que aquí está el problema, que le tengo que enviar sólo el texto seleccionado.

Código HTML:

```
                <form class="hilo_wrapper" action="crear_hilo.php?foro=<?php echo str_replace(" ", "%",$foro) ?>&subforo=<?php echo $subforo ?>"  method="post">
                <div class="data_hilo">
                    <input type="text" name="asunto" placeholder="Asunto:">
                </div>


                <div class="botones_crear_hilo">
                    <button type="button" accesskey="b" data-code="[b]" data-close="[/b]" onclick="insertText('txt1', '[b]','[/b]');" title="Negrita: [b]texto[/b] (Alt+B)">
                        <i class="fa fa-bold fa-fw"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" accesskey="i" data-code="[i]" data-close="[/i]" onclick="insertText('txt1', '[i][/i]');" title="Cursiva: [i]texto[/i] (Alt+I)">
                        <i class="fa fa-italic fa-fw"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" accesskey="u" data-code="[u]" data-close="[/u]" onclick="insertText('txt1', '[u][/u]');" title="Subrayado: [u]texto[/u] (Alt+U)">
                        <i class="fa fa-underline fa-fw"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" accesskey="q" data-code="[quote]" data-close="[/quote]" onclick="insertText('txt1', '[quote][/quote]');" title="Cita: [quote]texto[/quote] (Alt+Q)">
                        <i class="fa fa-quote-right fa-fw"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" accesskey="c" data-code="[code]" data-close="[/code]" onclick="insertText('txt1', '[code][/code]');" title="Código: [code]texto[/code] (Alt+C)">
                        <i class="fa fa-code fa-fw"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" name="img" accesskey="p" onclick="insertText('txt1', '[img][/img]');" title="Imagen: [img]http://www.ejemplo.com/imagen.jpg[/img] (Alt+P)">
                        <i class="fa fa-picture-o fa-fw"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" name="url" accesskey="w" onclick="insertText('txt1', '[url][/url]');" title="URL: [url]http://www.ejemplo.com[/url] o [url=http://www.ejemplo.com]texto[/url] (Alt+W)">
                        <i class="fa fa-link fa-fw"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" accesskey="s" data-code="[spoiler]" data-close="[/spoiler]" onclick="insertText('txt1', '[spoiler][/spoiler]');" title="Spoiler: [spoiler]texto[/spoiler]">
                        <i class="fa fa-list-alt fa-fw"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" name="mention" title="Mención">
                        <span class="fa-fw" onclick="insertText('txt1', '@');" style="display: inline-block">@</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-100">
                    <textarea  id="txt1" name="texto_hilo" placeholder="Texto:"><?php if (isset($_POST['vista_previa'])) { echo $vista_previa;} ?></textarea>

                    <div class="col-emoticonos-enviar">
                        <input type="submit" name="vista_previa" value="Vista previa">
                        <input type="submit" name="guardar_borrador" value="Guardar borrador">
                        <input type="submit" name="crear_hilo" value="Crear hilo">
                    </div>
                </div>


            </form>
```

Código Javascript:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function insertText(elemID, first, second) {
         var elem = document.getElementById(elemID);
         elem.value = second ? first + elem.value + second : first + elem.value;
     }
    </script>
```

Agradecería cualquier tipo de ayuda.

Comment: Es posible que no estés capturando bien el texto seleccionado con la función `window.getSelection()` que mencionaste en tu pregunta. ¿usando esto, te arroja algún error en la consola?. Te recomiendo además organizar tu código y, si te es posible, usa el [code snippet](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/430/78) para crear un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave Estoy probando con el siguiente ejemplo: http://help.dottoro.com/ljqxhfte.php y funciona...pero no con `textarea`...de hecho estoy haciendo pruebas de seleccionar cualquier parte de la web que no sea el textarea o inputs, y funciona. ¿No funciona con inputs?

Answer (score 0):

He buscado finalmente la respuesta, después de investigar y adaptar el código a lo que quería obtener. Es la parte del `<script>` la que he tenido que modificar y tras varias pruebas, ya me funciona correctamente.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function getSel(first,second) // javascript
    {

        // obtiene todo el contenido del <textarea>
        var txtarea = document.getElementById("txt1");
        // Posición inicial del texto que tenemos seleccionado
        var start = txtarea.selectionStart;
        // Posición final del texto que tenemos seleccionado
        var finish = txtarea.selectionEnd;
        // extraemos el texto seleccionado
        var sel = txtarea.value.substring(start, finish);
        // agregamos las etiquetas al texto seleccionado
        var sel = second ? first+sel+second : first+sel;
        // nos devolvería todo
        txtarea.value = txtarea.value.substring(0, start)+sel+txtarea.value.substring(finish, txtarea.length);
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pongo una variación de tu respuesta, dando más orden al código; a ver qué opinas.

```
// diccionario de estilos (pseudo-enum)
// https://stijndewitt.com/2014/01/26/enums-in-javascript/
var Estilos = {
  NEGRAS: 0,
  ITALICAS: 1,
  SUBRAYAR: 2,
  CITA: 3,
  MENCION: 4,
  tags: {
    0: { tag1: '[b]', tag2: '[/b]', nombre: 'Negritas' },
    1: { tag1: '[i]', tag2: '[/i]', nombre: 'Itálicas' },
    2: { tag1: '[u]', tag2: '[/u]', nombre: 'Subrayar' },
    3: { tag1: '[quote]', tag2: '[/quote]', nombre: 'Cita' },
    4: { tag1: '@', nombre: 'Mención' }
  }
};

// función principal
function aplicarEstilo(tipo) {
  var el = document.getElementById('editor');

  if (typeof(tipo) !== 'number' || el.selectionStart === undefined) {
    console.log('error: imposible procesar');
    return;
  }

  insertarTags(el, Estilos.tags[tipo].tag1, Estilos.tags[tipo].tag2);
}

// insertar los tags del estilo especificado
function insertarTags(el, tag1, tag2) {
  var ini = el.selectionStart;
  var fin = el.selectionEnd;
  var sel = el.value.substring(ini, fin);
  sel = tag2 ? tag1 + sel + tag2 : tag1 + sel;
  el.value = el.value.substring(0, ini) + sel + el.value.substring(fin, el.length);
  el.selectionStart = el.selectionEnd = ini + sel.length;
  el.focus();
}
```

Usando el código anterior, podrías cambiar el código HTML de tus botones de la siguiente manera (no pongo los estilos ni otros atributos, solo el código del botón):

```
<button id="btnBold" onclick="aplicarEstilo(Estilos.NEGRAS);">Negritas</button>
```

y sólo tendrías que variar el atributo del estilo a aplicar por dicho botón (`Estilos.NEGRAS` en este caso); esa es la parte interesante de esta variación: con el uso del objeto `Estilos` puedes mantener las etiquetas u otras propiedades (agregué como ejemplo una propiedad `nombre`) de manera centralizada y tus *handlers* `onclick` serán, en mi opinión, más limpios. [Aquí](https://jsbin.com/hikimaviqa/edit?html,js,output) puedes ver el ejemplo en ejecución.

---

Es interesante lo que intentas con tu código y esto podría evolucionar a un *plugin JavaScript* que agregues a tu página y que permita inicializar toda esta infraestructura con unas cuantas líneas de código. Pongo un ejemplo de dicha infraestructura (sin entrar en tantos detalles):

En el HTML:

```
<button id="btnBold"></button>
```

En el código JavaScript de la página:

```
editor = document.getElementById('editor');
btn = document.getElementById('btnBold');

// inicializar el botón para agregar etiquetas de negritas [b][/b]
var btnNegritas = new PluginEstilos({
  button: btn,
  textArea: editor,
  estilo: Estilos.NEGRAS,
  titulo: 'Negrita: [b]texto[/b] (Alt+B)',
  icon: 'fa-bold',
  acceso: 'b'
});
```

En el código JavaScript del plugin:

```
// PluginEstilos (v1.0)
// Permite asociar botones HTML con la acción de insertar tags de estilos.
(function() {
  // Método constructor
  this.PluginEstilos = function() {
    ...
  }

  // Métodos públicos
  PluginEstilos.prototype.desactivar = function() {
    ...
  }

  // Métodos privados
  function funcionHelperPrivada() {
    ...
  }
}());
```

Dicho plugin configuraría completamente el elemento HTML (`<button>`) además de los eventos requeridos para la funcionalidad requerida.

Si te interesa esta técnica, puedes leer [éste artículo](https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-your-own-javascript-modal-plugin) (en inglés) donde desarrolla la idea de los plugins JavaScript.